# GatsbyJS - Error with extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, static-site, gatsby

I'm using GatsbyJS to create a static site and am having several issues when trying to produce a production build.

Everything runs fine when I do `gatsby develop` but when I try `gatsby build` I am presented with the following error(s) for now:

```
/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:22
            if(c.initial) return;
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'initial' of undefined
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:22:8)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.mergeNonInitialChunks (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:21:16)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:275:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:273:21)
    at /home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:237:10)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsync (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:71:13)
    at Compilation.seal (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:525:7)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:397:15)
    at /home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:103:11
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:445:10)
    at /home/coder/Developer/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:417:12
```

Please let me know if I have posted too much information or can improve the quality of the question. I wanted to be as specific as possible. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For those who got to this page looking for answer: this problem is caused by anything apart from pages in the folder "pages". Moving styled and shared components to the root solved the issue.